# JS, Apply a new Date function to each UTC element of an array (and return the array)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, date, datetime

This:

`for(var i=0; i < timeValues.length; i++){
  console.log( new Date(timeValues[i]) );
}`
logs this in my console:

```
Fri Apr 29 2016 13:59:20 GMT+0200 (CEST)

Fri Apr 29 2016 14:14:37 GMT+0200 (CEST)

Fri Apr 29 2016 14:23:07 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

I want to make a function that returns it so I can call it and get the same result as an array. I tried this with jQuery :

```
timeValues = jQuery.map( timeValues, function( n, i ) {
  return ( new Date(n[i])  );
});
```

Basically I need this to output an array of formatted dates from a Millisecond UTC array as such format: `[yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS,yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS,yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS]`

Comment: You have to use `Array.prototype.map()`  like `var newTimeArray = timeValues.map(t  => new Date(t))`

Comment: You really helped me, thank you! Can you put as an answer so I make it when I have a few more points?